# Is there a way to have a 'rectangular' or 'diamond' like gradient effect for a div without any other element?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How can I specify gradient in a div background so as to achieve following kind of visuals?

[image]

I was able to achieve the appearance with 4 divs, but couldn't come up with solution having just *a single div* and its background property using gradients.

I think it's not possible even with before pseudo element.

Following is the idea of what I tried which makes it clear that 4 divs each with linear-gradient could be used:
[image]

Here is the code for above example:

```css
#box1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(225deg, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%);
  width: 107px;
  height: 116px;
  left: 228px;
  top: 335px;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

#box2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%);
  width: 107px;
  height: 116px;
  left: 308px;
  top: 415px;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

#box3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%);
  width: 107px;
  height: 114px;
  left: 153px;
  top: 410px;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

#box4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%);
  width: 107px;
  height: 115px;
  left: 234px;
  top: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; top:-300px;left:-100px">
  <div id="box1">
    <!-- -->
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <!-- -->
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <!-- -->
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
    <!-- -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the CSS patterns one can find online? e.g. http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ or https://bennettfeely.com/gradients/

Comment: @feeela Thanks for the links to very good examples. Will see if I can infer something from them.

Comment: @Downvoters : It'll be helpful if you add comment why you downvoted

Comment: include code ... actually you are including only image so it's like "code this for me"

Comment: @TemaniAfif Point noted.I thought it'll be faster to include image for me as well as viewer.. Anyways added code for 4 divs which I had tried.

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, no.. I agreed with what you said that it appears "code this for me". Thats why I said "Point noted". And that's why I edited the question and added the code I had tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176795/discussion-between-nitesh-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second one, you can simply use multiple gradient to create 4 backgrounds in each corner. You may notice that the colors should stop at 50% or less because the trick is to have a kind of triangle shape.

```css
.box {
  margin:5px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,#FF1794 0%, #FFF037 7.41%, #39ED94 13.72%, #00B0EC 25.23%, #FF1794 34.56%, #FFF037 40.76%, #39ED94 50%) bottom right,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 7.41%, #39ED94 13.72%, #00B0EC 25.23%, #FF1794 34.56%, #FFF037 40.76%, #39ED94 50%) bottom left,
   linear-gradient(to top left,    #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 7.41%, #39ED94 13.72%, #00B0EC 25.23%, #FF1794 34.56%, #FFF037 40.76%, #39ED94 50%) top left,
   linear-gradient(to top right,   #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 7.41%, #39ED94 13.72%, #00B0EC 25.23%, #FF1794 34.56%, #FFF037 40.76%, #39ED94 50%) top right;
   
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

For the first one ,You can consider pseudo-element and `clip-path`. The pseudo-element will have the same gradient as the main element in the opposite direction then with `clip-path` you cut two triangles from each side:

```css
.box {
  margin:5px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to right, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) right,
   linear-gradient(to left,  #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) left;
   
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom,#FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) bottom,
   linear-gradient(to top,   #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) top;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Move the pseudo-element and you will clearly understand the trick:

```css
.box {
  margin:5px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to right, #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) right,
   linear-gradient(to left,  #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) left;
   
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom,#FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) bottom,
   linear-gradient(to top,   #FF1794 0%, #FFF037 14.81%, #39ED94 27.72%, #00B0EC 50.23%, #FF1794 67.56%, #FFF037 81.76%, #39ED94 100%) top;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%);
  animation:move 2s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes move{
 to {transform:translate(100%)}
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: I'd love to know how to animate it zooming in or out.